# I just purchased a used hp mini laptop with a newly installed Ubuntu 20.4 and I can't seem to be able to create a user admin account

Tags: 20.04, hp, administrator

HP mini laptop 210-1000 with newly installed ubuntu 20.4 and I'm trying to create a user admin account but it's asking for a password So any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo adduser username` replacing "username" with your desired username and just pressing ENTER when it asks for a password (blank — no password)?

Comment: Otherwise, [sometimes](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#4-boot-ubuntu-server) the password is set to "ubuntu". Have you tried this?

Comment: Is this a new device? or a *refurbished* device with Ubuntu installed?   If it's the latter, you'll likely need to ask the refurbisher/reseller as they can use their own passwords which are usually provided on a written page of text given with the receipt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)